# How to implement both tab bar and side menu in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

For sidemenu I am using the `SWRevealViewController` framework and For tab-bar I am taking 3 Viewcontrollers example **A**, **B** and **C**. I want to display tab bar in initial Viewcontroller for that purpose in `didfinishlaunch`
method in app delegate. I have mentioned front viewcontroller as tab-bar and rear Viewcontroller as side menu and I am also successful in moving to side menu. But from that side menu I am unable to navigate the view controller. Please suggest me

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
SideMenuViewController *sidemenuVc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SideMenuViewController"];
HomeViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];
SWRevealViewController *revealController = [[SWRevealViewController alloc] initWithRearViewController:sidemenuVc frontViewController:vc];
//[self .navigationController.pushViewController:vc animcated:YES];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:revealController  animated:YES];
```

Comment: put some code snippet what you are doing, so that it give clear idea.

Comment: sure plz wait i will provide shortly

Comment: You  said given code is working only it creates problem while you navigate from side menu. Provide code of sidemenu and format it properly as it become more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You should create storyboard like this

[image: Storyboard]

or try below one[image: Storyboard2]